# How to create multiple xml request by only changing one field?

Tags: java, xml

I need help to find the approach of how to create xml multiple times while I will be changing only two fields everytime and rest of the fields would be same as now. Please tell me the way to do it in java? 
This is the sample xml below: 
I would be changing the value of `<Id>` and `<Originator>`

```
<TransactionBlk>
  <Id>NIK</Id> 
  <CorrelationId /> 
  <Originator>NIK</Originator> 
  <Service>GetIns</Service> 
  <VersionNbr>1</VersionNbr> 
  <VersionNbrMin>0</VersionNbrMin> 
  <MsgNm>Req</MsgNm> 
  <MsgFormatCd>XML</MsgFormatCd> 
</TransactionBlk>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crate one class contain all this parameter as class variable, create getter and setter method. Create object of class set value by using setter method.

You can use `JAXB API's` class to convert your java object into XML format.

```
The JAXBContext class provides the client's entry point to the JAXB API.  
It provides an abstraction for managing the XML/Java binding information   
necessary to implement the JAXB binding framework operations: unmarshal,  
marshal and validate.
```

Here is [Doc reference](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.7/docs/index.html) for convert your Java object into XML.

Here are tutorial for same [Tutorial Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/xml/javax_xml_bind_jaxb.htm)

**Sample Code :**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="TransactionBlk_REQ",namespace="http://TransactionBlk.com")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)  
public class TransactionBlk  
{ 
   @XmlElement(name = "Id")
   private String id;  

   @XmlElement(name = "Originator")
   private String Originator;   

   //Your getter and setter method.
}

TransactionBlk bean = new TransactionBlk();
//Set your parameter value here

StringWriter responseWriter = new StringWriter();  
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(TransactionBlk.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();  
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(bean, responseWriter);
String xmlStr = responseWriter!=null?responseWriter.toString():null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) to transform `XML`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is printing a "boilerplate" document with changes in those two values, a, you could use the DPH (Desperate Perl Hacker) approach: simply assemble it as text, pausing to print the values at the appropriate places. To be safe, you should pre-scan the values to make sure they don't contain the <, >, or & characters and escape those if you find them.

For something more complex, or if you want to start learning how to do it "properly", look at the standard XML APIs for Java: DOM (the Document Object Model, an in-memory tree model of a document), SAX (an event-stream view of a document), and JAXP (tools to take an XML document and parse it into DOM or SAX so you can read it, and to take DOM or SAX and write those out as XML syntax). JAXP also provides standard APIs for invoking XPath to search a document and XSLT to apply a stylesheet to a document, so taken together these cover a huge percentage of the basic operations on XML.

You might want to look at some tutorials on using Java to manipulate XML. I'm certainly biased, not least because they published one of my articles, but in my experience IBM's DeveloperWorks website (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/) has had better-than-average material for learning about XML and other standards.